# How should I test classes against their inherited types?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I've previously seen a good solution to the issue of testing against interfaces, whereby you create an abstract test class for the interface, then inherit from that for the test for each class which derives from that interface, using a `CreateInstance` method to provide an instance of the given class.  e.g.

```
public interface INamable {string Name{get;}}

[TestClass]
public abstract class INamableTests
{
    protected abstract INamable CreateInstance(string name);
    [TestMethod]
    public void NameCorrectlyAssignedTest()
    {
        var expected = "this is my name";
        var instance = CreateInstance(expected);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, instance.Name);
    }
}
```

However, whilst the above approach works well when our class only implements one interface, things get a bit more complicated when multiple interfaces are inherited.  We can get around this by having multiple test classes inherit from each abstract test class for each interface; but that solution only works for one level of inheritence.  i.e. If we have another subclass in our inheritance hierarchy we need to repeat ourselves / don't get the benefit of the tests written for our base class.

To demonstrate, if we add the code at the end of this question to the above, we'd want to test:

```
INamable   \
IStartable  |- IBatchJob - BatchJob - AutoStopBatchJob
IStoppable /
```

But since we can't inherit from multiple classes, our test inheritance is limited to:

```
INamableTests - IBatchJobTests - BatchJobTests - AutoStopBatchJobTests
```

So to run `IStartableTests` and `IStoppableTests` for `BatchJob` and `AutoStopBatchJob` (and any other class using the `IBatchJob` interface) we need to repeat the code for calling those tests.

Is there a better approach for this?

---

```
public interface IStartable {void Start();bool IsRunning{get;}}
public interface IStoppable {void Stop();bool IsRunning{get;}}
public interface IBatchJob: INamable, IStartable, IStoppable {}
public class BatchJob: IBatchJob 
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public bool IsRunning {get; private set;}
    public BatchJob(string name) {Name = name;}
    public void Start() {IsRunning = true;}
    public void Stop() {IsRunning = false;}
}
public class AutoStopBatchJob: BatchJob 
{
    System.Timers.Timer batchTimer;
    public AutoStopBatchJob(string name, TimeSpan maxRunTime): base (name) 
    {
        batchTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        batchTimer.AutoReset = false;
        batchTimer.Interval = maxRunTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        batchTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    }
    public override void Start() 
    {
        base.Start();
        batchTimer.Start();
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stop();
    }       
}
[TestClass]
public abstract class IStartableTests
{
    protected abstract IStartable CreateInstance();
    [TestMethod]
    public void StartSetsRunningToTrue()
    {
        var instance = CreateInstance();
        Assert.AreEqual(false, instance.IsRunning);
        instance.Start();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, instance.IsRunning);
    }
}
[TestClass]
public abstract class IBatchJobTests: INamableTests
{
    public abstract IBatchJob CreateInstance(string name);
    //I've extended INamablTests, so those will get run.
    //However, how should I test IStartable and IStoppable?
}
[TestClass]
public class BatchJobTests: IBatchJobTests
{
    public static BatchJob CreateInstance(string name) => new BatchJob(name);
    public IBatchJob CreateInstance(string name) => BatchJobTests.CreateInstance(name);

    //do I have to implement nested classes for these interfaces for every derived class?
    [TestClass]
    public class BaseClassIStartableTests : IStartableTests 
    {
        protected IStartable CreateInstance() => BatchJobTests.CreateInstance("Default Name");
    }
    [TestClass]
    public class BaseClassIStoppableTests : IStoppableTests 
    {
        protected IStoppable CreateInstance() => BatchJobTests.CreateInstance("Default Name", initialRunningState:=true);
    }
}
```

Comment: side note: I don't see the point of separating the `IStartble` interface from the `IStopable` interface. Surly if you can start something, you should be able to stop it and vice versa....

Comment: @ZoharPeled; no point; this is just demo code I knocked up as an MVCE / trying to use names that would be a bit more intuitive/meaningful that `Foo`/`Bar`.

Comment: Well in that case, Kudos. Most users tend to use names like classA, classB that makes the entire thing almost unreadable.